# Restricting access to ECS EC2 instance types using IAM Policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have a query regarding restricting access to AWS Resources using IAM Policies. I was able to restrict ec2 resources to *. micro, *. nano, *. small, *. medium. However, when I was trying the same thing in ECS (Elastic Container Service), I was able to deploy even the *. large, *. xlarge, *.2xlarge, etc instances types in cluster section with the same IAM permission set. In IAM for ECS I am not able to find any particular way where we can restrict the ECS-EC2 cluster sizes. Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about showing your IAM policy in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the policy below

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "VisualEditor0",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"ecs:*",
"ec2:*"

```
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
  },
  {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
      "Condition": {
          "ForAnyValue:StringNotLike": {
              "ec2:InstanceType": [
                  "*.nano",
                  "*.micro",
                  "*.small",
                  "*.medium"
              ]
          }
      }
  }
```

]
}